# Which approach is better : space versus time complexity

Tags: performance, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have an algorithm (very basic), for which i have two solutions in mind, the complexities of two are : 
**Approach 1 :**

```
Space complexity: O(n)
Time Complexity : O(n)
```

**Approach 2 :**

```
Space complexity: O(1)
Time Complexity : O(nlogn)
```

which approach to opt for, i am looking for best practice in situation such as this.

**Edit 1** : My input is infinitely large.

Comment: Depends on your needs.

Comment: Depends on your target system. If it is a 8051 with 127 bytes RAM, you will know which option you would prefer ;)

Comment: Now you are nitpicking ;) There is always the "ignored and forgotten" c to consider. The "real" O formulas have them. ``c + O(c1*N)``. This really is important in edge cases....

Comment: @user2225104, O() doesn't measure resource *use*, it measures how the need for resources *scales*. Your earlier comment is completely wrong as its claims the O(1) solution *uses* less memory than the O(N) solution.

Comment: Only as wrong as using O-notation is in general. Typically anyone is aware that they talk about scaling. And anyone is aware that this scaling sometimes does not matter. Just like trivial sorting of 4 numbers is faster than using quicksort for that.

Comment: For infinitely large input, nothing is going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithmic evaluation definitely depends on the problem.

For example your **Approach 1** might be great if your `n < 2^30` in which case your algorithm will use the rest of `2^30` bits in the space consumed.

You **Approach 2** will be more scalable since it doesn't need any major additional memory. Its better for someone to wait a little longer for a result (`nlogn` is better than `n^2`) than crashing the system which is supposed to work.

So, it all depends on your requirement.